# Golang channel is asleep

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, channel

I'm new with golang channels and could not underestimate why does program behavior changes if I specify channel buffer size

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func channels(in <-chan bool, out chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case _ = <-in:
            fmt.Println("Close")
            close(out)
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println("Out")
            out <- 1
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    in := make(chan bool)
    // in := make(chan bool, 1)
    out := make(chan int)

    go channels(in, out)

    i := 0

    // Loop:
    for n := range out {
        fmt.Println(n)

        i += 1

        if i > 10 {
            fmt.Println("Send close")
            in <- true // Here it is became asleep
            return
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

Output is:

```
Out
Out
1
1
Out
Out
1
1
Out
Out
1
1
Out
Out
1
1
Out
Out
1
1
Out
Out
1
Send close
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /home/user/go-lessons/3/chan_4.go:39 +0x2c3

goroutine 19 [chan send]:
main.channels(0xc820072060, 0xc8200720c0)
    /home/user/go-lessons/3/chan_4.go:16 +0x241
created by main.main
    /home/user/go-lessons/3/chan_4.go:27 +0x97
exit status 2
```

If I replace `in := make(chan bool)` with `in := make(chan bool, 1)` It works properly. Why does it happen?

Comment: The error actually says why, but it's not immediately obvious.  While one goroutine (main) waits to send to `in`, channels it's waiting to send to `out`. When you add a buffer, the send doesn't block (because there's room in the buffer) .  Otherwise, it's a deadlock as each these is waiting for the other.  I recommend you consider whether you really need that select in channels.

Comment: @DanFarrell This is just a learning code. I try to use one channel to manipulate the flow and other to produce some data. I made this to understand how channels works and how to make asynchronous communication between two goroutines. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the main goroutine is stuck writing to `in`

```
in <- true
```

and the other goroutine is stuck writing to `out`

```
out <- 1
```

If you make the write to out a `case` aswell it should work:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-in:
        fmt.Println("Close")
        close(out)
        return
    case out <- 1:
        fmt.Println("Out")
        break
    }
}
```